# recommendation for a good JSF profiler

Tags: java, jsf, profiling

Any recommendations for a good JSF profiler?
I am using Tomcat 6
JSF2, Hibernate & Spring

Comment: what app server are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, then the builtin profiler or the ones which are available as a plugin will in most cases already suffice. It all depends on the features and the level of detail the profiler provides.

Eclipse for Java EE ships with [TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) which can also be installed as a plugin in Eclipse versions lacking the profiler. Just deploy project to server, rightclick server instance and choose *Profile on server*. You'll be brought to *Profiling and logging* perspective wherein you can examine the profiler results.

Netbeans has its own [profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org/) which is based on JDK's builtin [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) profiler (actually, it's the other way round, the VisualVM was born out of the Netbeans profiler ages ago).

Talking about VisualVM, you can also use it independently if you have the JDK installed. You can use it to profile Tomcat as well. Here's a [nice blog article](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2009/11/monitoring-tomcat-with-java-visualvm.html) about that.

You can by the way stresstest webapplications using [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/).

#### See also:

- [Eclipse TPTP tutorial](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t52038.html)
- [Netbeans profiler tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-intro.html)

Comment: HI, I tried the profiler. The problem is that it calculate time from the beginning of the application. I mean, let's say that I moved to a new page, it adds time to method that i have used in both pages and it's hard to track which method consume how much. any idea?

Answer (score 3):

There is a new JSF profiler:

**[XRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/xrebel/)**